# Why are files shuffled after I rename them?

Tags: python, rename, shuffle

I need to rename all images in a folder, however when I do this, they come back in a random order, and I need the first file to be 000000, second 000001, but the actual 000000.png is not the first file in the original folder.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path,"{:06d}".format(i))+'.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `i` variable set to?

I expect you want:

```
for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
```